# Unable to convert special characters on reading XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am using the following code to import XML into a dataset:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(file.FullName);
if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0) //not empty XML file
{
    da.ClearFieldsForInsert();
    DataRow order = dataSet.Tables["Orders"].Rows[0];
    da.AddStringForInsert("ProductDescription", order["ProductDescription"].ToString());
}
```

Special characters such as `&apos;` are not getting translated to `'` as I would have thought they should.

I can convert them myself in code, but would have thought the `ReadXML` method should do it automatically.

Is there anything I've missed here?

EDIT:

Relevant line of XML file:

```
 <ProductDescription>Grey &apos;Aberdeen&apos; double wardrobe</ProductDescription>
```

EDIT:

I then tried using `XElement`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
XElement order = doc.Root.Elements("Orders").FirstOrDefault();
```

...

```
if (order != null)
{
    da.ClearFieldsForInsert();
    IEnumerable<XElement> items = doc.Root.Elements("Orders");

    foreach (XElement item in items)
    {
        da.ClearFieldsForInsert();
        da.AddStringForInsert("ProductDescription", item.Element("ProductDescription").value.ToString());

    }
```

Still not getting converted!

Comment: It would help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including the XML and how you're diagnosting the resultant DataSet.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents), `&apos;` is a valid XML escape code.

However, it is not necessary to escape `'` in element values.

```
<ProductDescription>Grey 'Aberdeen' double wardrobe</ProductDescription>
```

is valid XML.

Workaround aside, a standards compliant XML parser should honour the predefined entities, wherever they occur (except in CDATA.)

This frailty, and deviation from standard XML parsing, of [`Data.ReadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0z9zxd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is noted in the documentation. I quote:

> The **DataSet** itself only escapes illegal
>   XML characters in XML element names and hence can only consume the
>   same. When legal characters in XML element name are escaped, the
>   element is ignored while processing.

---

Due to its limitations, I wouldn't use `DataTable.ReadXml` for XML parsing. Instead you could use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) something like this,

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

...

var doc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
var order in doc.Root.Elements("Order").FirstOrDefault();
if (order != null)
{
    da.ClearFieldsForInsert();
    var productDescription = order.Element("ProductDescription");
    da.AddStringForInsert(
        "ProductDescription",
        productDescription.Value);
}
```

Comment: Is the same true for `&amp;`? Because that is not getting converted either.

Comment: @EMett, apologies, my original answer was wrong, I've edited.

Comment: This does not really answer my question. I need to know how to get the escape codes translated into ordinary text when using `ReadXML`

Comment: I've updated the question again. In short, `DataTable.ReadXml` is broken.

Comment: @EMett, basically, don't use `DataTable.ReadXml`, use `XDocument` instead.

Comment: @EMett, to directly answer your question, `DataTable.ReadXml` should parse all predefined entities but does not. You've missed the part of the documentation where this failing is stated. To fix your problem use another parsing mechanism from the framework that is standards compliant. I've illustrated one option in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I will do so.

Comment: I tried using XElement, but still does not convert. I edited the question to include a demonstration of this.

Comment: @EMett your best bet is to follow Jon Skeet's advice. Without the some sample failing XML it will be hard to continue.

Comment: I cannot include the whole XML file as it does not belong to me.

Comment: Anyway, as there does not seem to be an elegant solution, I am doing the parsing manually. Thanks for trying!